How to set multiple resource URI as Moneta user
The situation is that my Angular app need to have the authentication & authorization setup for 2 consuming downstream application that use different security protocols. To achieve the same, resource URI for consumer app 1 is set as the Moneta user, then the authentication works well for Consumer app 1 but not for consumer app 2. If its done for the consumer app 2, then it fails for the consumer app 1 (error received : Moneta user is null). Is there a way to setup both the resource URI as the Moneta user ?
The situation is that my Angular App need to have the authentication & authorization setup for 2 consuming downstream application that use different security protocols. To achieve the same, resource URI for consumer app 1 is set as the Moneta user, then the authentication works well for Consumer app 1 but not for consumer app 2.
